# AngularJS - Array in other JS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, variables, global

I am currently trying to make a website. My main (AngularJS) controller requests JSON data, filters it and pushes it into an array. Now I would like to use said array in a different javascript file and I can't wrap my head around how to do it.

I read the option to create a service multiple times now however I believe that this is specifically for passing variables between two controllers.
Moreover, the other options did not work out for me as well.

What is the best approach to this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What was the problem that you encountered while you tried to use `services`?

Comment: @DavidR It seemed to me that using services was to let variables be passed between two controllers and not from one controller to a JS file

Answer (score 0):

You can create global javascript variable which will be accessible to both  your controller as well as other JS file. Now update its value from controller which will change it at global level.

Then in the next file just retrieve it.